# Extract value of json-like variable in bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a variable in bash that is an output of Amazon EMR create command;

```
CLUSTER=$(aws emr create-cluster ...)
echo $CLUSTER
```

the output is like this:

```
{ "ClusterId": "j-9YWMBYN98LN7" }
```

What I need to do is to extract the value `j-9YWMBYN98LN7` to a new variable, something like:

```
ID=$CLUSTER.(ClusterId)
```

Of course the above command doesn't work. I have tried with jq but no luck.

```
ID=$(jq -r '.ClusterId' $CLUSTER)
```

The thing is I'm not even sure what type $CLUSTER is. How do I extract the value `j-9YWMBYN98LN7` there? Thanks

Comment: if might not matter, but did you try `ID=$(jq -r '.ClusterId' "$CLUSTER")` ? (dbl-quoting CLUSTER var). Good luck.

Comment: Doesn't work either, here is the output: `jq: {
    "ClusterId": "j-1FZMHAPPDD0LG"
}: No such file or directory.` Thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If

```
echo $CLUSTER
```

gives you

```
{ "ClusterId": "j-9YWMBYN98LN7" }
```

then

```
ID=$(awk  'BEGIN{FS="\""}{print $4}' <<< "${CLUSTER}")
```

should do it.

```
echo "$ID"
j-9YWMBYN98LN7
```

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3685928 : You're welcome pal !

Comment: This solution works in bash, but not in others shells. This is my variation to ash:     `ID=$(echo $CLUSTER | awk  'BEGIN{FS="\""}{print $4}')`

Comment: @JavierYáñez  Cool, Thankfully the question is tagged bash

Answer (score 13):

If you want to use `jq`, you can do it this way

```
 ID=`echo ${CLUSTER} | jq -r '.ClusterId'`
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work either. I think this $CLUSTER is not json (may be string, I don't know). Here is the output: `cat: {: No such file or directory
cat: "ClusterId":: No such file or directory
cat: "j-1FZMHAPPDD0LG": No such file or directory
cat: }: No such file or directory`

Comment: My bad, it should be `echo` instead of `cat`. I corrected my answer and it should work now.

Comment: It works now, thanks a lot, but I can only upvote your answer as I have accepted the other one :)

Comment: @user3685928 You can (and should) accept this answer instead.

Comment: simple & works ✨

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
ID=$(echo "${CLUSTER}" | sed 's/{ "ClusterId": "//' | sed 's/" }//')
```

That will isolate `j-9YWMBYN98LN7`, or whatever is between the last set of quotes, into the variable `$ID`.

I get the feeling there is more to what you need as you are probably planning on using the contents of `$ID` for something and there may be more efficient ways to capture that value for you. Maybe if you can explain a bit more how you plan on using the value we can provide even more actionable answers.

Comment: I'm writing a script to automate the process of creating an EMR cluster and adding jobs to it. I need this Cluster ID in the job-adding step like this: `aws emr add-steps --cluster-id $ID`. Again, I'm not sure what type of the variable $CLUSTER here, and I understand that just by giving you guys the output it could be hard

Comment: Anyway, the output of your command is still the same as $CLUSTER `{ "ClusterId": "j-1FZMHAPPDD0LG" }`

Comment: It is odd that is did not work for you. You can check it via `echo '{ "ClusterId": "j-9YWMBYN98LN7" }' | sed 's/{ "ClusterId": "//' | sed 's/" }//'` For me it did indeed output `j-9YWMBYN98LN7`. No worries though, I like @sjsam 's awk answer better as well.